# Trying to select nth elements from a list

Tags: list-manipulation

I'm trying to take the nth element of each sublist. Below is an example list:

`exlist = {{{1,2}, {2,6}, {4,1}}, {{2,3}, {3,1}, {2,4}}, {{5,6}, {7,5}, {6,7}}};`

`want:    {{{1,2}, {2,3}, {5,6}}, {{2,6}, {3,1}, {7,5}, {{4,1}, {2,4}, {6,7}}}`

I tried to use [[All, 1]], but my actual code goes up to 20 and I want to have it automated so I don't have to put [[All, 1]],[[All, 2]],[[All, 3]]. This might be easier than I thought but I couldn't find an alternative. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

use

```
Transpose@{{{1,2},{2,6},{4,1}},{{2,3},{3,1},{2,4}},{{5,6},{7,5},{6,7}}}
```

> {{{1,2},{2,3},{5,6}},{{2,6},{3,1},{7,5}},{{4,1},{2,4},{6,7}}}

Comment: Thank you so much! Can't believe it was easy as that...